# PXDBScalar SOOrderKvExt attribute bool

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to use PXDBScalar to bring in a boolean attribute from the Sales Order user defined fields tab to the Shipment screen.

I found another stack overflow post that helped with the creation of the SOOrderKvExt DAC, and I am able to retrieve the value of the valueNumeric (decimal) field via my PXDBScalar attribute, but I cannot find a way to convert the value to a bool so it properly displays as a checkbox on the screen.  I tried setting the data type for my unbound field to bool, but got a data type conversion error.  I also tried leaving the field as a decimal and just changing the control type on the screen, but it always displays as checked regardless of the value.  Any idea how I can convert the decimal value to a bool in the PXDBScalar attribute or another solution?

Code snippets provided below.

SOOrderKvExt

```
[PXCacheName("SO Order Attributes")]
[Serializable]
public class SOOrderKvExt : IBqlTable
{
    public abstract class recordID : BqlGuid.Field<recordID> { }
    [PXDBGuid(IsKey = true)]
    public Guid? RecordID { get; set; }

    public abstract class fieldName : BqlString.Field<fieldName> { }
    [PXDBString(50,IsKey = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName ="Name")]
    public string FieldName { get; set; }

    public abstract class valueNumeric : BqlDecimal.Field<valueNumeric> { }
    [PXDBDecimal(8)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Value Numeric")]
    public decimal? ValueNumeric { get; set; }

    public abstract class valueDate : BqlDateTime.Field<valueDate> { }
    [PXDBDate]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Value Date")]
    public DateTime? ValueDate { get; set; }

    public abstract class valueString : BqlString.Field<valueString> { }
    [PXDBString(256)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Value String")]
    public string ValueString { get; set; }

    public abstract class valueText : BqlString.Field<valueText> { }
    [PXDBString]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Value Text")]
    public string ValueText { get; set; }
}  
  
  
}
```

PXDBScalar

```
   #region UsrSOBlindShip
    [PXDecimal(8)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName="SO Blind Ship", IsReadOnly=true)]
    [PXDBScalar(typeof(Search2<SOOrderKvExt.valueNumeric,
        LeftJoin<SOOrder, On<SOOrder.noteID, Equal<SOOrderKvExt.recordID>>,
        LeftJoin<SOShipLine, On<SOShipLine.origOrderNbr, Equal<SOOrder.orderNbr>>>>,      
        Where<SOShipLine.shipmentNbr, Equal<SOShipment.shipmentNbr>>>))]
    public virtual decimal? UsrSOBlindShip{ get; set; }
    public abstract class usrSOBlindShip: PX.Data.BQL.BqlDecimal.Field<usrSOBlindShip> { }
    #endregion
```

Thanks
Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a boolean calculated field. Similar to this :

```
public class SOLineExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.SO.SOLine>
  {
    #region UsrIsZero
    [PXBool]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName="Is Zero")]
    [PXFormula(typeof(Switch< Case<Where<SOLine.orderQty, Greater<decimal0>>, False>, True >))]
    public virtual bool? UsrIsZero { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrIsZero : PX.Data.BQL.BqlBool.Field<usrIsZero> { }
    #endregion
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Rick, Are you suggesting that I should add a second custom unbound field that calculates the bool value from the first field with the PXDBScalar?  I guess that would work.  Thanks for the help

Comment: Correct. A second custom field.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks for the suggestion.